# Unity freeze when play button is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity through an udemy course.

Now I am stuck at a point where unity screen freezes when I hit the play button.
It happens in the spawn manager for the random positioned enemies and powerups
the `IEnumerator` for enemy works perfectly, but as soon as I add the same for the powerup, and hit the play button, it freezes.

When I comment out the powerup section in the spawn manager, and restart unity, it works perfectly.

What should I do for my powerup spawn to work ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _enemyShipPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] powerup;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(EnemySpawnRoutine());
        StartCoroutine(PowerupSpawnRoutine());
    }

    public IEnumerator EnemySpawnRoutine()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            float enemyPositionX = Random.Range(-8.34f, 8.34f);
            Instantiate(_enemyShipPrefab, new Vector3(enemyPositionX, 6.39f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PowerupSpawnRoutine()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // float powerupPositionX = Random.Range(-8.622f, 8.622f);
            int randomPowerup = Random.Range(0, 3);
            Instantiate(powerup[randomPowerup], new Vector3(Random.Range(-8.622f, 8.622f), 4.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `PowerupSpawnRoutine` the `while(true)` is always going to run as its an infinite loop. You don't `yield` anywhere inside it.

You should add a delay in your `PowerupSpawnRoutine` as well.

```
public IEnumerator PowerupSpawnRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // float powerupPositionX = Random.Range(-8.622f, 8.622f);
        int randomPowerup = Random.Range(0, 3);
        Instantiate(powerup[randomPowerup], new Vector3(Random.Range(-8.622f, 8.622f), 4.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);

        // this e.g. will spawn powerup after every 5 seconds.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... sorry  !  i  saw it too late...i solved it myself  later back  then..thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in by [Muhammad Farhan Aqeel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62403306/7111561) you are not `yield`ing anywhere inside of the `while(true)` loop in `PowerupSpawnRoutine`.

---

However, as complete alternative here instead of using Coroutines at all you could also use [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) in your use case:

```
[SerializeField] private float enemySpawnDelay = 5f;
[SerializeField] private float powerupSpawnDelay = 5f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    // The first parameter is the initial delay so 0 makes the first call
    // immediately.
    // The second parameter is the repeating delay
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(EnemySpawnRoutine), 0f, enemySpawnDelay);
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(PowerupSpawnRoutine), 0f, powerupSpawnDelay);
}

private void EnemySpawnRoutine()
{
    float enemyPositionX = Random.Range(-8.34f, 8.34f);
    Instantiate(_enemyShipPrefab, new Vector3(enemyPositionX, 6.39f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}

private void PowerupSpawnRoutine()
{
    // when getting random indices use the actual length of the array to be more
    // flexible and secure against errors
    int randomPowerup = Random.Range(0, powerup.Length);
    Instantiate(powerup[randomPowerup], new Vector3(Random.Range(-8.622f, 8.622f), 4.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```